# Estou fazendo um sistema de pesquisa na minha view de filmes e deu um erro em relação ao pedido Web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, razor

(Decidi fazer outro post, como concelho de um outro utilizador)

Na minha view de Filmes tem uma lista de todos os filmes que tem na base de dados e eu adicionei `um botão, uma caixa de texto e 2 radio buttons(para escolher se quero pesquisar por Nome do filme ou por Categoria do filme)` . No `If` só está especificado a Categoria porque o Nome está por Default em primeiro lugar. O meu objetivo é fazer um sistema de pesquisa por Nome ou Categoria. Depois de mudar o código do `If` o erro anterior foi resolvido mas apareceu um novo relativo ao Model.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    { 
        MovieViewModel[] movies = db.MoviesData.Select(movie => new MovieViewModel
        {
            MovieID = movie.MovieID,
            MovieName = movie.MovieName,
            MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
            MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
            MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
        }).ToArray();

        if (searchBy == "Categoria")
        {
            return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieCategory==search || search == null).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieName != null && (search == null || x.MovieName.StartsWith(search))).ToList());
        }
    }
```

View Principal dos Filmes:

```
    @model WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel[]


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Movies", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search By: </b>@Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Nome", true) <text> Nome </text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Categoria") <text> Categoria </text> <br />
    @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Nome </b></th>
        <th><b>Categoria </b></th>
        <th><b>Ano de Lançamento </b></th>
        <th><b>Descrição do Filme </b></th>
        <th></th>


    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.MovieName</td>
        <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
        <td>@item.MovieYear</td>
        <td>@item.MovieDescription</td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieID })
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

O novo erro não está específicado em nenhuma linha em concreto. Foi um erro de processamento Web. Esse é o erro:

`System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel[]'.`

Comment: Teria como adicionar a view toda? mas de modo geral o erro é que sua view espera 1 objeto e você está passando uma lista.

Comment: @Barbetta Editei a view completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No inicio da sua *view* quando você declara o tipo dela, deveria estar uma lista do objeto.
Mude de

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel[]
```

para

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.MovieViewModel>
```

Isso acontece porque você está retornar uma lista para a *view*

```
if (searchBy == "Categoria")
{
    return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieCategory==search || search == null).ToList());//Retornando uma lista
}
else
{
    return View(movies.Where(x => x.MovieName != null && (search == null || x.MovieName.StartsWith(search))).ToList());//Retornando uma lista
}
```

Caso sua lista possa retornar `null` talvez você queira fazer também uma validação, algo do tipo:

```
@if(Model == null || Model.Count() == 0)
{
    <span> Não foram encontrados dados</span>
}
else
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th><b>Nome </b></th>
            <th><b>Categoria </b></th>
            <th><b>Ano de Lançamento </b></th>
            <th><b>Descrição do Filme </b></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.MovieName</td>
                <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
                <td>@item.MovieYear</td>
                <td>@item.MovieDescription</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.MovieID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MovieID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```